# Excel VSTO fails to load if there are VBA macros

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-2007, vba

I have an excel XLS developed with Visual Studio Tools For Office (VSTO) 2005. Most of the code is in C# VSTO, but there is also a VBA macro to implement a worksheet function. I'm *not* trying to have the VBA and C# talk to each other, or anything like that. It's just a worksheet function.
   But in Excel 2007 -- if the user has macros disabled, then that VBA prevents the VSTO from running. (Error message: "The customization assembly could not be found or could not be loaded.") If I remove the VBA, then the VSTO loads fine.
   But the VBA macro isn't crucial, so I don't want to abort loading of the entire VSTO sheet. The rest of the functionality should work even if macros are turned off.

Is there any way I can force Excel to continue loading the VSTO even if the VBA is disabled?

Comment: is there any detail with this error message, maybe inner exception?

Comment: no, no error message. Just "The customization assembly could not be found or could not be loaded." without any further inner exception. Enabling permission for VBA macros fixes it, so it's clear what's going on here. But i want to be able to load the rest of the sheet, even if the VBA macros won't work.

Comment: Are you enabling the VBA macros only or the VBA object model access?

Comment: I did test my solution (VSTO 3.0 for Office 2007) and It works with macros disabled, but fails to call the macros if VBA object model access is disabled (I call the macros from VSTO). Can you provide any other details? Does your solution work in Excel 2003 with macros disabled? Could it be the case that you access VBA model from VSTO?

Comment: have you tried running your code in debug under Excel 2007?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1e6ht9c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx to check how to get more information from VSTO Runtime

Comment: The worksheet function doesn't need to be VBA, it can be exposed through VSTO. Keep a backup, but try wiping out ALL code, forms and modules (all VBA) from the workbook, and saving as an Excel workbook (NOT macro-enabled). If the worksheet function is only valid in that workbook, consider creating a VSTO Excel workbook project and implementing the worksheet function in that project.

Comment: Have you check to see if other adding are loaded and if so what version of. Net they are using? Or if the vba calls any Net assembles

Comment: What happens if you save the workbook as a trusted document? or run it in a trusted location.

Comment: Think you may need to have a macro enabled workbook (.xlsm) to use .VSTO addins

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your Excel file in the most recent format in Excel (xlsm). I have programmed different Excek files in this way with C# code and VBA macros.